# How to combine multi array in python

Tags: python, arrays, django

I want to combine array from 3 different arrays for my project (web) using Django. I give some example:

Input:

Array A: `['A','B','C']`

Array B: `['1','2','3']`

Array C: `['a','b','c']`

Desired Output:

```
[['A','1','a'],['B','2','b'],['C','3','c']]
```

Comment: Use zip to combine them.

Comment: I did it. Yes, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip`

```
In [76]: a=[1,2,3]

In [77]: b=[1,2,3]

In [78]: c=[1,2,3]

In [79]: zip(a,b,c)
Out[79]: [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)]

In [80]: map(list, zip(a,b,c))
Out[80]: [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a list of lists:

```
list(zip(a,b,c))
```

If you want a single list:

```
output = a
output.extend(b)
output.extend(c)
```